# Differentiation using Chain Rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ if $y=7+5^{x^2+2x-1}$.

So far I have done $\frac{dy}{dx}=(5^{x^2+2x-1})'$. Now, the RHS can be found by $(e^{\ln 5\cdot (x^2+2x-1)})'=e^{\ln 5\cdot (x^2+2x-1)}(x^2+2x-1)'\ln 5=5^{x^2+2x-1}(2x+2)\ln 5$.

However, my textbook says the answer is $(2x^3+6x^2+2x-2)(5^{x^2+2x-1})$. Where did I go wrong? Thanks.

Comment: your work is correct. your textbook is not.

Comment: I don't know where your textbook authors went wrong, but if the function is as you've stated, your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

First note that
$$\frac{d}{dx}a^{f(x)}=a^{f(x)}(\ln a)\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$$
So now we have
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left[7+5^{x^2+2x-1}\right]$$
$$=\frac{d}{dx}[7]+\frac{d}{dx}\left[5^{x^2+2x-1}\right]$$
$$=0+5^{x^2+2x-1}(\ln 5)\frac{d}{dx}\left[x^2+2x-1\right]$$
$$=5^{x^2+2x-1}(\ln 5)\left(2x+2\right)$$
$$=2\cdot 5^{x^2+2x-1}(x+1)\ln 5$$

Answer (score 0):

Your work is correct
$$\frac { d\left( 7+5^{ x^{ 2 }+2x-1 } \right)  }{ dx } =\frac { d\left( 7 \right)  }{ dx } +\frac { d\left( 5^{ x^{ 2 }+2x-1 } \right)  }{ dx } =0+\left( 5^{ x^{ 2 }+2x-1 } \right) \ln { 5 } \frac { d\left( x^{ 2 }+2x-1 \right)  }{ dx } =\\ =\left( 5^{ x^{ 2 }+2x-1 } \right) \ln { 5 } \left( 2x+2 \right) \\ $$